# Stream error logs

Tags: sed, logs

I want to stream the contents of an error log (`/log/spo.error`) as it's written, but pipe the stream through `sed` before I see it. How can I do that?

Comment: Tried `tail`? Like `tail -f /log/spo.error | sed 's/whatever/you want/'`.

Comment: Use a `fifo`/`named pipe` and read from it?

Comment: How do I set up the log file to be a fifo? Also how do I pipe one fifo through a SED or AWK processes?

Comment: See my answer below for information about piping syslog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tail -f was the way to go ty. I will ask more about FIFOs later ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using syslog (classical syslog), in your `/etc/syslog.conf` file add this line:

```
*.*        /tmp/fifo
```

where `/tmp/fifo` is a pipe you create using `mknod p /tmp/fifo`.

Restart your syslog service so that it reads your new configuration and now all logs will get dumped into the pipe. Then you can `tail` the pipe if you'd like or do whatever to read it (just keep race conditions in mind).

Comment: Ok, what if its not a log that I want to pipe. Say I just have a text file thats being appended to and I want to read it as it gets appended is syslog still the tool I want to use?

Comment: If it's just regular text, I would do what @manatwork suggested in the comments. `tail -f /file` will show you the appends to that file in real time. You can then use `sed` to parse it.